# What are recommended resolutions, sizes and ratios for designing Windows 8 apps mockups?

Tags: applications, windows-8

I'm about to start working on some mobile Windows 8 apps, and I'm a bit confused about the recommended resolutions, sizes and ratios for supporting different devices. For iPhone, for example, I normally create mockups of 960×640px, for iPad 2048x1536px and so on. But I'm lost about size for Win8, and especially for Windows Phones.

**What resolution / screen size / aspect ratio should I use for creating Win 8 smartphone apps mockups?**

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joona's comment had the information I was looking for.

From Microsoft's [Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> Windows Phone 8 supports phones that have WVGA, WXGA, and 720p
>   resolutions.

- WVGA - 480 × 800 - 15:9 - Scaled resolution: 480 × 800
- WXGA - 768 × 1280 - 15:9 - Scaled resolution: 1.6x scale 480 × 800
- 720p - 720 × 1280 - 16:9 - Scaled resolution: 1.5x scale, 80 pixels taller (53 pixels, after scaling) 480 × 853

Answer (score 1):

The minimum resolution in which Windows Store apps will run is 1024x768.The minimum resolution required to support all the features of Windows 8 (including multitasking with snap) is 1366x768. More info in the link below.

[Windows 8 Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx)

Comment: That seems to be mostly for desktop. I'm currently working on the first wireframes, so I'm wondering more about the size for smartphones, but for the mockups mainly. I'll edit the question so it's clearer.